# Kotlin: Compiler doesn't infer generic type for some operators

Tags: generics, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, kotlin, jvm-languages

Why can't Kotlin's compiler infer the generic type with some operator calls? For example:

```
class Example {

    operator inline fun <reified T : Any> unaryMinus(): T {
        ...
    }

}
```

Using it in a main method...

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val ex = Example()

    val works: Boolean = ex.unaryMinus()
    val doesntWork: Boolean = -ex
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wait, what does `val works: Boolean = ex.unaryMinus()` mean? How can that work?

Comment: This is a bug, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: @voddan What do you mean? The type is inferred from the value's type. Alternatively `val works = ex.<Boolean>unaryMinus()`

@AlexanderUdalov Will do. Thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: Oh, ok.  My bad, sorry

Comment: @AlexanderUdalov https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issueMobile/KT-10453

Comment: @jire when this bug is resolved can you please update the question to state it was a bug, and what version resolved it.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately the result of a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10453